# react-router-dom doesn't install all the packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

[image: what is the solution for this problem i get when installing npm install react-router-dom]

I tried npm install react-router-dom@latest

But still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It seems like the packages were installed.

Comment: You need a react-router-dom for your react app and it is installed successfully. If you are seeing warnings after installing react-router-dom, you can try running npm audit fix --force to fix any potential vulnerabilities in your dependencies. However, this is not always necessary and it is up to you whether or not you want to run this command.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

- Create a new empty node project

> ```
> % mkdir router-test
> % cd router-test
> % npm init -y
> ```

- Then install react router

> ```
> % npm install react-router-dom --save
> ```

- *package.json* file now should have a new library reference:

> ```
>     "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
> ```

Copy it into *package.json* file from your project and update packages with

> ```
> % npm install
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what node version you are using.

If you are working on a new project, consider using node 18.

```
node --version
v18.12.0


npm install react-router-dom@latest

added 8 packages, and audited 9 packages in 3s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Look what happens instead with node 6.

```
node --version
v6.17.1

npm install react-router-dom@latest
/home/ralle/projects/test
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=16.8
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@>=16.8
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.6.1 
  ├── @remix-run/router@1.2.1 
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=16.8
  └── react-router@6.6.1 

npm WARN react-router-dom@6.6.1 requires a peer of react@>=16.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-router-dom@6.6.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>=16.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-router@6.6.1 requires a peer of react@>=16.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No license field.`
```